# When to use 'Static Methods' in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bunch (may be 10 to 15 ) methods in my C# code all of which are 'Static'. Obviously, all of them are called with the ClassName. All works well. But, are they any advantages/disadvantages of using them that way? or would I get any performance benefit if I do not use 'Static' for my methods?

Comment: That question might be a little bit philosophic. Thing is - you can not clearly answer that, without knowing anything about your software design.

Comment: Rather than an advantage - a disadvantage is that this can make your code a little harder to unit test.  You can't inject a static class into your code and so makes it very difficult to mock.

Comment: There are some good answers here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/111938/which-is-a-better-practice-helper-methods-as-instance-or-static

Answer (score 4):

Technically there is slight performance benefit when you are using static method, because you don't need to load instance reference to stack when executing method. But that is really minor optimization which you will not notice.

From programming point of view static methods are hard to mock and they introduce strong coupling with implementation in your code. Also you lose benefits of abstraction and polymorphism when use static methods.

You can make static private methods from instance methods which don't use instance data. But public static methods usually give you problems with mocking and dependency injection, so usually I avoid them. One exception is factory methods which used to create instances of class - `Loan.CreateLongTermLoan` (thus you can't have constructor with custom name in C#, but you want some descriptive name which describes details of created instance) or `Loan.Parse`.

Comment: Most of my methods interact with Database and pass values back to the caller. Few methods have heavy data that is passed back...So, will having them as Static do any harm?

Comment: Size of returned data does not affect on what type of methods to use - static or instance. If you are not going to create unit-tests for your business logic and you are completely sure you will always use same data provider, then you can use static methods. Your system will be hard to test, and it will be strongly coupled. But not all systems need testability and flexibility.

Comment: Great. Testability of the application is not of priority and the dataprovider will not change. So, I guess I'll leave them as Static.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worrying about the performance benefit of static methods over instance methods then you're micro-optimizing and without doubt prematurely optimizing. You should worry about good class design before you worry about this sort of thing!

If you've got methods that don't operate on the state of an instance then they are good candidates for being static methods. For example, factory methods are an obvious use of static methods.

If you've got methods that operate on the state of the instance then they need to be instance (non-static) methods. For example, a method that changes a member variable could not be static.

FYI : At the IL level all instance methods are called via a [CallVirt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instruction, even if they are not virtual. This allows the runtime to generate a `NullReferenceException` if you call a method on a null reference. A static method is called via the [Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instruction.

Comment: +1: for clear cut answer.

Comment: Can you please explain this "If you've got methods that don't operate on the state of an instance then they are good candidates for being static methods. If you've got methods that operate on the state of the instance then they need to be instance (non-static) methods."?

Comment: @Abhi - I've added more info to the answer

Answer (score 1):

No performance benefit for being static or not.

If you don't need an instance of the class in a method, then it's a candidate for being marked as `static`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with static method comes the moment you need a sub-class.

Static methods cannot be overridden in sub-classes, hence your new classes cannot provide new implementations of the methods, making them less useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **conceptual question**. Does the method …

- belong to a *specific instance*? Then it's not static.
- belong to the *class* rather than to a specific instance? Then it's a prime candidate for being static.

Note that static methods can't access instance members (non-static members) of an object.